# auto resize when changing browser size

Tags: css, resize

what is the fastest (or best) way to make everything (images, letter-types, colored boxes/tables,background(colored & image)...) in a website

i know that you need to use %, but i then need to do everything individually.
also is it possible to give measurements like width and height both px measurements and %?

e.g. you say that a div needs to have a color blue and you give him a width of 100px, but you want it to resize and scale along with the browser, can you place a 100% or something that defines this?

it should look like this:
width:100px 100%;

Answer (score 3):

You should look at "Responsive Web Design". There are many resources on the web, but here's one in particular which is a good introduction to the topic:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

To your specific question, look at the min-width CSS property to get the effect you're after :)